# Persisting JPA Entity using CrudRepository

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa-2.0, spring-data

Having issues saving JPA Entity through CrudRepository.  It seems to return the original object that was passed to it without persisting the object to the database.  I know this is not the correct way to do it but for testing purposes if I place an instance of TransactionSynchronizationManager before the save, it seems persist correctly.  This leads me to think maybe there an issue the Transaction Manager?

In addition if I discard the repository and use the Entity Manager (em) I get the same result, however if I call em.flush(), I get the Exception "Transactionrequiredexception, No Transaction in Progress".

```
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public User save(User user) {

//  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    //Object persists when adding following line
//  TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(emf , new EntityManagerHolder(em)); 
        return  userRepository.save(user);
    }

}


@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"..."})
@Import(value={DataContextConfig.class,SecurityConfig.class})
public class AppConfig{
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {".."})
@Import(DataConfig.class)
public class DataContextConfig {

}

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode=AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@EnableJpaRepositories(value={"com.repository"}, entityManagerFactoryRef="entityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef="transactionManager")
@PropertySource("classpath:data.properties")
public class DataConfig {
... 
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() { 
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager(); 
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory((EntityManagerFactory) entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager; 
    }
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {      
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("...");
        factory.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties());
        factory.setDataSource(dbSource());
        return factory; 
    }


        @Bean
        public DriverManagerDataSource dbSource(){  
            DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
            driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
            driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
            driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));      
            return driverManagerDataSource;
        }

    }
```

I have uploaded a small project that isolates the exception.  Zip and run AccountTester.class http://www14.zippyshare.com/v/81636273/file.html

Comment: You are not opening session before `save`. did you?

Comment: Very helpful if put full stack trace.

Comment: There is no Stacktrace. Fails without Errors

Comment: I think you are trying to `userRepository.save(user);` without opening Hibernate session and trnsaction at least this is the reason you are getting ` No Transaction in Progress` error.

Comment: I have the @EnableTransactionManagement(mode=AdviceMode.ASPECTJ) Annotations inside the @Config Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there were multiple @EnableTransactionManagement(mode=AdviceMode.ASPECTJ) annotations within the application.  This was cause of the problem, after removing the one within the Neo4j @Configuration Class the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

As per your sample project. 
Below are the only classes modified to avoid your `TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress` problem and successfully insert an account:

```
package com.jpa.base.repository;

import com.jpa.base.entity.Account;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long> {

    public Account findByEmailAddress(@Param(value = "emailAddress") String emailAddress);

    public Account findByAccountId(@Param(value = "accountId") Long accountId);

}
```

[Original for reference](https://gist.github.com/donovanmuller/ebff90215d7953439d6b#file-accountrepository-java)

You need to mark your Spring Data JPA repository with `@Repository` (Not your service). [See here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

```
package com.jpa.base.service.impl;

import com.jpa.base.entity.Account;
import com.jpa.base.repository.AccountRepository;
import com.jpa.base.service.AccountService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service("accountService")
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Account findByAccountId(Long accountId) {
        return accountRepository.findByAccountId(accountId);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Account findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        return accountRepository.findByEmailAddress(emailAddress);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Account save(Account account) {
        return accountRepository.save(account);
    }

}
```

[Original for reference](https://gist.github.com/donovanmuller/ebff90215d7953439d6b#file-accountserviceimpl-java)

Note the changes of removing `@Repository` from the service (needs to be on your Spring Data JPA repository interface) and using the `accountRepository` to persist your entity in your `save(...)` method.

Not sure why you were trying to use the `EntityManagerFactory` to create a new `EntityManager` (if you really need an `EntityManager` instance you should just inject the configured `EntityManager`, not the factory). This also happens to be the reason for your `TransactionRequiredException`.

Anyhoo, why bother with all that when you can just use your repository to persist your entity.
Running your `AccountTester` now produces the desired functionality:

```
...
Hibernate: insert into account (email_address, name, version) values (?, ?, ?)
INFO : com.jpa.base.entity.AccountTester - Account Saved: Account Id: 3, Email Address:james.brown@outlook.com, Name: James Brown, Version: 0
```